# PC is buzzing under load

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, hardware-failure, gpu

I've got a mini-itx small factor PC

- GTX 980
- i5 6600
- SF PSU 600W

When it's under a load, like running a game for example, it starts buzzing usually.

These are two examples, not from my box but the same sound.
On the 1st one buzzing starts when the guy is running a game - same as me.

https://youtu.be/9AjFYnKTdnw?t=22

https://youtu.be/tIvoH2gd6Vg

I've got a few ideas what it might be, would be glad to hear someone who's faced such a problem though. What is it?

Comment: Maybe a heat problem, and then you are hearing the fan(s).

Comment: Can you be more specific? Exactly what device is buzzing?

Comment: @Albin I'm not sure myself. The small factor case doesn't help identifying which device emits the sound. My bet goes for the PC speaker. It can be a really loud coil whine as well perhaps.

Comment: @harrymc fans indeed go louder as heat rises and buzzing may be heat related but it doesn't sound like a fan noise. Check any of the YouTube links I posted. Could this be coming from a fan?

Comment: You first need to find the cause, please see my answer.

Comment: @topr: Have you connected all required power cables to the graphics card?

Comment: @JamesP yes I have, would it even work without them connected?
I'm narrowing the suspect to most likely be a CPU temp BIOS alert. Will adjust it to tolerate higher temp just to see if it stops buzzing. If that's it - I'll think on improving the cooling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your first link :

> This noise is actually an error beep of Award BIOS for overheating cpu, so if you already checked the temps (and if they are ok) then there is something weird with your cpu or board﻿

Another comment :

> In my case, for the same buzzing voice the problem was in dying cooler. I changed it and problem solved! There are two coolers, which one? The big one

This agrees with my own estimate, that your computer is overheating.
Many causes are possible, including (as in the second comment) defective cooling.

If you are using Windows, you may use [Speedfan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php)
to display the temperatures in the traybar and see their evolution.

The problem might come from the GPU. But if it comes from the CPU, then simply
lowering CPU usage by a trivial amount can do wonders.

To do :
In Control Panel -> Power options -> Change plan settings -> Change advanced power settings, expand Processor power management and set the Maximum processor state to 98% for Battery and Plugged in.

However, no solution by software can really fix defective hardware.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. I'm pretty sure that's the case - heat. I was wondering could it be overloaded PSU, on the other hand. I had been monitoring temps with [CAM](https://camwebapp.com/) before posting this question. GPU gets up to 81C, CPU, don't remember from the top of my head, I think it was up to 68C or so. Yesterday I checked I've got a BIOS alert set for 70C on CPU. I'll change it to 80C and see how it affects the buzzing. I've got some cooling improvements lined up but these temps, although quite high, are not critical. First I'd like to ensure it's the alert, not something worse.

Comment: Even 85C is still usually acceptable.

Comment: Yupp, I've seen this comment under YT video.
I've changed the BIOS setting CPU temp alert from 70C to 80C and run like this for w few days now. It 'solved' the problem. I mean it doesn't buzz. Also confirmed the CPU goes max to 75C. It's not a surprise. Stock CPU cooler, small factor case and GPU raising temp of the whole box. Unfortunately this GPU exhaust doesn't entirely go outside the case. I don't think such temp is any risk. It just runs rather loud under load. Some cooling improvements shall come :)

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to try to isolate the causes: Check - for example - if the buzzing is there when there is just load on the CPU but not on the Graphic Card. If thats not the case try to isolate other causes. I assume you check if it's just with the one game or with others as well?!

The other way is to "disconnect" possible sources like speaker, etc. as you discovered yourself. But then you would have to open the case... But in the end you might not be able to avoid to open up the case anyway to check more thoroughly.

My favourite approach would be to pinpoint the source first (speaker, fan, power supply, etc., without disconnecting it)

Comment: @topr Since you are a software developer, I assume you know how to do isolate the different causes, if not just ask.

Comment: sure I know. I was about to do this. There are two things why I thought I ask first. 1) if anyone recognises out of own experience such buzzing, this would save me some investigation. 2) if I open the case then temp drops and it doesn't buzz so the examination changes the state of the system ;)

Comment: @topr ah, ok different approach then....  yes, I had similar problems but it was always a different source, most of the were already mentioned except for one where the power supply (not the fan) made the noise.